# How to get a custom CSS style statement using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I find myself in the position of processing some unusual HTML from clipboard data created by MS Word.

My problem boils down to this:
This works (returns `none`):

```js
console.log($('<span style="mso-list:Ignore;display:none"></span>').css('display'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This doesn't work (returns `undefined`):

```js
console.log($('<span style="mso-list:Ignore"></span>').css('mso-list'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Why is this not working (do they white-list the CSS statements?) and how can it be worked around? Do I have to parse the style attribute myself?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick trick to get value of this property:

```js
console.log($('<span style="mso-list:Ignore"></span>').attr('style').split('mso-list:').pop())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```